# Is a list content is in a long string?

Tags: python, string, list

I want to know whether a list content is in a long string. such as:

```
aa=["column","is","the","word","others", "excludition"] # the list content
bb="from the long text" #the long string
cc=[wd in bb for wd in aa]
```

but the `cc` is `[False, False, True, False, False, False]`.
I want to need the True.  if one of the items is true.

How to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `any`:

```
cc=any([wd in bb for wd in aa])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
aa=["column","is","the","word","others", "excludition"] # the list content
bb="from the long text" #the long string
cc=[wd in bb for wd in aa]

if any(word in bb for word in aa):
    print('yes')
```